# Error on Google Analytics tracking code for a Google Site

Tags: google-analytics, google-sites

When i run the tracking code on my google site, it gives the following error :

> Error on line 8

Should I ignore it? Or is it really an error? in which case what do i do?

Comment: You're not providing enough information for anyone to properly help you. Add some more information to you post - cut and paste the section in question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Google Sites, you will first need to [enable Analytics](http://support.google.com/sites/bin/topic.py?hl=en&topic=1046096)
and then add your Analytics Web Property ID (`UA-xxxxx-xx`) in the General settings under Statistics at sites.google.com/site/***(your site name)***/system/app/pages/admin/settings or in Google Apps at sites.google.com/a/***(your domain name)***/system/app/pages/admin/settings